# Prove that if $m$ and $n$ are integers and $mn$ is even, then $m$ is even or $n$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have this assignment:

Prove that if $m$ and $n$ are integers and $mn$ is even, then $m$ is even or $n$ is even.

How should I begin?

Comment: What can you say about $mn$ if $m$ and $n$ are both odd?

Comment: Break it into three cases: n,m both even, n,m both odd, or one even and one odd.

Answer (score 3):

Proof by contradiction. Suppose $m$ and $n$ are odd. Write $m = 2k+1$ and $n  = 2l+1$. What is $mn$ then ?

Comment: What is the difference between contradiction and contrapositive?

Comment: @Alim In general, there isn't much of one, but in particular to prove $P\Rightarrow Q$ with contrapositive you start with $Q^c$ and try to reach $P^c$.  For contradiction, you try to start at both $P$ and $Q^c$ and try to arrive at *any* contradictory statement (whether it is $P^c\wedge P$ or something else).  For this case, proving by contrapositive ends with the line "then mn is odd."  whereas via contradiction ends with the line "then mn is odd, but we said that mn was even and it can't be both simultaneously."

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are still struggling. I'll fill in the details for a proof by contrapositive.

Recall what the contrapositive actually *is*: for statements $P$ and $Q$, we have that $P\to Q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg Q\to\neg P$, where $\neg Q\to\neg P$ is called the "contrapositive." In the context of your problem, we have the following formulation:

- $P: mn$ is even.
- $Q : n$ is even or $m$ is even.

Hence, we are trying to prove $P\to Q$. However, it will be simpler to prove the contrapositive, $\neg Q\to\neg P$. If we can prove the contrapositive, then we will have proved the original statement because $P\to Q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg Q\to\neg P$. So write out what $\neg Q$ and $\neg P$ actually are:

- $\neg Q : n$ is odd and $m$ is odd.
- $\neg P : mn$ is odd.

Thus, to prove $\neg Q\to\neg P$, we must prove the following statement: "If $n$ and $m$ are odd, then $mn$ is odd. To this end, let $n=2k+1$ and $m=2\ell+1$, where $k,\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we have the following:
$$
mn = (2\ell+1)(2k+1)=4\ell k+2\ell+2k+1=2(2\ell k+\ell+k)+1=2\eta+1,
$$
where $\eta=(2\ell k+\ell+k)\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $mn$ is an odd integer, and we have proven $\neg Q\to\neg P$, thus proving $P\to Q$, as desired. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the contrapositive: if $m=2a+1$ and $n=2b+1$ both are odd, then $nm$ has to be odd too. You can show this by expanding 
$$
(2a+1)(2b+1).
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can first prove that each integer is odd or even by induction on the absolute value of the integer. Then You can use this fact to derive a contradiction from supposing that $m$ and $n$ are both odd, letting you infer that $m$ is even or $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $m$ is odd. Since $mn$ is even, $2\mid mn$. But $m$ is odd so $\gcd(2,m)=1$ now by the [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) we have $2\mid n$. That is, $n$ is even.